# Valid displayAt() range in GMS

Tags: dm-script

Images can be displayed at a specific location with the DisplayAt() command.
Does anyone know the valid range?

For example, DisplayAt(-9000, -9000) is that valid? What is the total valid range?

Of course in the example  the image would not be seen within the GMS frame, but that is exactly what I need.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, negative values are completely ok and will indeed "place" the image outside the visible range of the window.

There is nothing like a "valid" range - the coordindates are just numbers. ( There is likely a limit when the value exceeds the value-range of the internallly used variable type to store the coordinates, possiblye long (4 byte signed integer). )

Just be aware that concepts like "front most" window will also apply if an image is outside the "visible" range. Images will f.e. also show up in the ImageBrowser regardless of their position on the workspace. The same is true for iterating through images on a workspace using f.e. `CountImageDocuments()` and `GetImageDocument()`

Some commands ( I think `ShowImage()` ) might have addtional code to ensure that images stay "visible" and might therefore shift the image back into the workspace range. Also using "auto-arrange" will take images from the "off" and place them back into the visible range.

So if you deliberatly use "off-screen" display, this is ok, but it might create some unintended side-effects. What is the exact purpose of using it this way? There might be more suitable concepts. (f.e. one can create imageDocuments and add ImageDisplays to them without the need of showing the imageDocument.) Image may also be temporarilly "hidden". Finally, one might condiser shiftung "unwanted" images onto a separate workspace.